# Bug with keep_geom_type using overlay how='difference' returning geometrycollection when keep_geom_type=True? Using geopandas 0.10.1

Tags: python, pandas, gis, geopandas

My understanding of geopandas overlay is that when I specify to `keep_geom_type=True` is that it will maintain a the left geometry as the same type. For example the left GeoDataFrame has Polygons/MultiPolygons and doing the overlay will make sure that the result will have geometries that are Polygons/Multipolygons. However, with my example I am getting a GeometryCollection for one of the results. I believe this was supposed to be fixed with pull [#1582](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/1582). But here is the specific example of it not working and I would like to note I am using geopandas=0.10.1.

Let's say I have my left dataframe as `left_df`

[image: GeoDataFrame display for left GeoDataFrame]

and my right dataframe as `right_df`

[image: GeoDataFrame display for right DataFrame]

taking the difference using overlay

```
res_difference = left_df.overlay(right_df, 
                                 how='difference',
                                 keep_geom_type=True,
                                 make_valid=True)
```

where `res_difference` shows

[image: GeoDataFrame as a result of overlay]

and the geometry in index 4232 is a Geometry Collection when it should be a MultiPolygon.

Using sjoin I was able to find that 4232 (blue MultiPolygon) intersects with 4182 and 4184 (orange polygons) and plot the intersecting shapes.

[image: Intersecting Polygons where blue is 4232 and orange is 4182 and 4184]

The line string is showing up because they share the same border with a differences I took out of the polygons from before where you can see the river like cutouts. I think there is a bug but would be interested to see what people have to say and would like to know if this is a bug?

Comment: That indeed looks like a proper bug. Can you report it to https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues please? Ideally with a sample of data to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @martinfleis sure thanks for commenting!